# Storing Multiple Values in an Array into Excel using Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm having issues with writing values in an Array into excel column. At the moment I can only print the first data set within the array meaning:

within Excel:

COL:A
Mazda3

COL:B
Civic

COL:C
Corolla

COL:D
Altima

```
      tmpList.extend([mazda, honda, Toyota, Nissan])
      df = pd.DataFrame(tmpList)
      df = df.transpose()
      xlsfile = 'pandle.xlsx'
      writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsfile, engine='xlsxwriter')
      df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1",startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
      writer.save()
```

Ideally I want:

COL:A
Mazda3, CX7, CX5

COL:B
Civic, Accord, Pilot

COL:C
Corolla, Camry, Sienna

COL:D
Altima, Pathfinder, Maxima

//EDIT

So i'm able to write multiple data set, but it's the inverse, it's printing everything by column and not row as I would prefer.

```
xlsfile = 'pandle2.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsfile, engine='xlsxwriter')
#df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'])
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['1A', '2B', '3C', '4D', '5E', '6F', '7G', '8H', '9I'])
df = df.transpose()
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1",startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: What is input data? How you get `CX7`, `CX5` for first row?

Comment: So I have a REST API that's pulling data which is sensitive, so the values within the array such as mazda are variables assigned to a particular API pull and so fourth.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
mylist.append([x,y,z,])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

basically pass your array into pandas module. in this example you have to import pandas as pd if you want to use this sample.